# How can I add a CSS declaration to an XML document using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have many XML files that I want to process with XSLT. I want the result to include custom CSS for the purpose of displaying the files a distinct way in Oxygen’s Author mode.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alto xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto-v2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#">
<!—more XML-->
</alto>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!—A series of templates that transform the XML-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>
<alto xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto-v2.0.xsd">
<!—more XML-->
</alto>
```

What do I need to add to my stylesheet to get the declaration to display in each XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`xsl:processing-instruction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/#the-xml-stylesheet-processing-instruction) instruction.
So your stylesheet could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">href="my-style.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>
<alto xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto-v2.0.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">href="my-style.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>
  <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
```

at the end of the stylesheet or make sure you edit the template you have for `match="/"` and insert the `<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">href="my-style.css"</xsl:processing-instruction>` there.